# FullCalendar - Calling a modal that is inside a foreah loop

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar

Background check: I'm currently doing a modal view for the details of events. One for the calendar view, and the other for a list view. Now my problem is although I can call the modal from the list view, I can't do the same in calendar view (through eventClick method). So my aim is to call a modal that is inside a laravel foreach loop.

Here's the view code:

Calendar side within the id="calendarView"

```
<div class="m-portlet__body">
    <div id="calendar2"> </div>
</div>
```

List side within id="listView"

```
<tbody>
    @for ($day = 1; $day <= $day_count; $day++)
        <tr class="fc-list-heading">
            <td class="fc-widget-header" colspan="3">
                <a class="fc-list-heading-main">{{ Carbon::today()->format('F') }} {{ $day }} </a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        @foreach($trainings as $training)
            @if ($training->start_date->format('j') == $day &&
                $training->start_date->format('F') == Carbon::today()->format('F') &&
                $training->start_date->format('Y') == Carbon::today()->format('Y'))
                <tr class="fc-list-item m-fc-event--accent">
                    <td class="fc-list-item-time fc-widget-content">{{ $training->start_time }} to {{ $training->end_time }}</td>

                    <td class="fc-list-item-title fc-widget-content">
                        {{ $training->title }} - @if($training->type_id == 1) Lecture Only @elseif ($training->type_id == 2)Assessment Only @else Lecture and Assessment @endif
                        <div class="fc-description">{{ $training->venue }} - 
                            @if($training->total_participants - $training->joined_participants < 5 && $training->total_participants - $training->joined_participants > 0) <a class="m--font-warning"> {{ $training->total_participants - $training->joined_participants }} slot/s remaining </a>
                            @elseif($training->total_participants - $training->joined_participants == 0) <a class="m--font-danger">Full</a>
                            @else <a class="m--font-success"> {{ $training->total_participants - $training->joined_participants }} slot/s remaining </a>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td class="text-center fc-list-item-alt fc-widget-content">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-danger m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" data-target="#m_modal_{{ $training->id }}" >
                            <i class="fa fa-eye fa-md"></i>
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-danger m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" data-target="#modal_delete{{ $training->id }}" >
                            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-md"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            @endif
            @continue

        @endforeach
    @endfor
</tbody>
```

Modal for the event (for view and edit)

```
@foreach($trainings as $training)
            <div class="modal fade" id="m_modal_{{ $training->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    @include('admin.training_index.show')
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal fade" id="modal_delete{{ $training->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h3 class="h3">Confirm Delete?</h3>  
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h6>Are you sure you want to delete event for {{ $training->start_date->format('F j, Y') }}? </h6>                             
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="/admin/training/{{ $training->id }}/delete" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</a>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

And the script for calling the modal from fullCalendar

```
$(function() {
      $('#calendar2').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'month',
        eventClick:  function(jsEvent) {

            $("#m_modal_" + jsEvent['id']).modal();

            //$("#m_modal_4").modal("show");
            // $("#m_modal_" + jsEvent['id']).modal("show");
        },
        dayClick: function(date) {
            alert('Clicked');
        },
        events: [
            <?php foreach($trainings as $training)
                { 
            ?>
                {
                    id: "{{ $training->id }}",
                    title: "{{ $training->title }}",
                    start: "{{ $training->start_date }}",
                    end: "{{ $training->start_date }}"

                },

            <?php } ?>
        ]
      })
    });
```

Comment: it seems a bit crazy to repeat all the HTML for the modal _n_ times over (where _n_ is the number of events in your calendar. The normal way to approach this problem would be that you would create the modal HTML once, with some empty elements within it ready to contain data. Then, when eventClick runs you'd open the modal, and place data from the event (given to you by fullCalendar of course) into the relevant spaces in the modal's inner HTML.

Comment: by the way, fullCalendar has its own "list" type view, you don't really need to make your own - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list-view :-)

Comment: Lastly what do you mean by " I can't do the same in calendar view" exactly? What goes wrong when you try? Console error? Some other unexpected behaviour? What debugging have you done? Your code, although inefficient in some ways (as I mentioned above), looks like it would work - the event is clicked on, and the "show" command runs to open the relevant modal. The only possibility is, depending on your version of bootstrap you might need to write `.modal("show")` rather than just `.modal()`. Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: solved it. just needed to put another set of modal view outside of the fullcalendar <div>. for the number of events, I have set it to only show what's on the current month viewed, then trigger an ajax for moving the month set forward/back

Comment: It wasn't clear that you'd put any modals inside the fullCalendar div...your code sample above doesn't indicate that, or at least doesn't make it clear. As for showing only what's on the current month, I agree that's a sensible approach, but you seem to have missed my point that really you only need one modal div full stop, no matter how many events you have.